# How to type default list initializers in functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

I have the following function

```py
def foo(main_list = None):
    if main_list is None:
        main_list = []

    # do stuff with main_list
```

This is a [common Python paradigm](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/correctness/mutable_default_value_as_argument.html) because if you have a default list, that list stays the same for all default calls. So you get around that by setting it to be `None`, and then resetting it the the actual default list inside the function.

When typing this, I'd like to do:

```py
def foo(main_list: List[int] = None):
    if main_list is None:
        main_list = []

    # do stuff with main_list
```

But Mypy complains because now I'm storing `None` to a `List[int]` which isn't right.

Should I...

1. Make `main_list` be of type `Optional[List[int]]`
2. Add in a `# type: ignore` (which will also remove all the typing from the other parameters that work just fine)
3. Some other better way of getting around this

(I really hope that the answer is #3, which is why I'm asking. Right now in my code, I have opted for option #2.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `Optional[List[int]]`. You're not losing anything by making the parameter optional - you're explicitly handling `None` within the body of the function - so there's no reason to not use the correct type. It's Pythonic to treat empty lists and `None` identically anyways.

The problem with `# type: ignore`, as you mentioned, is that it suppresses type checking for other parameters.